# How to get a json file from a website in iOS?

Tags: objective-c

When open link below with a browser:

https://maps.google.co.kr/?q=seoul&output=json

It will start to download a json file.

How to get this file in iOS??

In android it seems using the inputStreamReader to get the content.

Please give me some advise or sample code about it.

Thanks for your help~~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

It was a very simple way...

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.co.kr?q=%@&output=json", 
                       [address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
                                                        encoding:NSKoreanEncoding  

                                                     error:&error];
```

It returns a google search result with a full info(address,content,lat,lon etc).

But I don't know why people don't use this way...

If anyone knows about it please tell me~~ thanks~~

Answer (score 1):

You can download it, for example with my class https://github.com/sakrist/ASyncURLConnection

Comment: It goes error...I think it is because the url is not a file address.